# WebDriver not able to run on Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a web scraping project in which I have to scrape some LinkedIn information, hence I am using selenium in Python, I have installed the Selenium in Python, but now I try to use Selenium driver to control Chrome, there is error displayed which says **"Module is not callable".**

I don't know how can I resolve this. Please help.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/Intel/Desktop/chromedriver")

from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/Intel/Desktop/chromedriver")
```

when I try to execute:

```
driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/Intel/Desktop/chromedriver")
```

the error displayed as:

> 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect:

```
driver=webdriver.chrome("/Users/Intel/Desktop/chromedriver")
```

This is correct:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Intel/Desktop/chromedriver")
```

In Python, letter **'c'** will be in **upper case** in the function **chrome()**.

You get more information, just click on [this](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).